# CSOM site provisioning error: The request uses too many resources

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I continue to get an error (sometimes) when provisioning a web using CSOM.  According to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163082.aspx), this error is returned when the CSOM request exceeds 2MB.  I watched the call in Fiddler and the request is not greater that 2MB.  What could the problem be?  Below is the code and request/response from fiddler:

```
   using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(url))
    {

       cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

       WebCreationInformation information = new WebCreationInformation();
       information.WebTemplate = "CMSPUBLISHING#0";
       information.Description = "My New Site";
       information.Title = "My New Site";
       information.Url = "newsite";
       // Currently all English, could be extended to be configurable based on language pack usage
        information.Language = 1033;
        information.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = false;

        cc.Web.Webs.Add(information);
        cc.ExecuteQueryRetry();
}
```

Fiddler Request:

```
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009"><Actions><ObjectPath Id="1158" ObjectPathId="1157" /><ObjectIdentityQuery Id="1159" ObjectPathId="1157" /></Actions><ObjectPaths><Method Id="1157" ParentId="923" Name="Add"><Parameters><Parameter TypeId="{8f9e9fbe-189e-492f-884f-98f9ef9cc4d6}"><Property Name="Description" Type="String"></Property><Property Name="Language" Type="Int32">1033</Property><Property Name="Title" Type="String">Manuals</Property><Property Name="Url" Type="String">manuals</Property><Property Name="UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite" Type="Boolean">false</Property><Property Name="WebTemplate" Type="String">CMSPUBLISHING#0</Property></Parameter></Parameters></Method><Property Id="923" ParentId="384" Name="Webs" /><Identity Id="384" Name="7e19049d-e009-2000-008d-b659834a548f|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:a43f2ef7-f1aa-423a-ad26-59b66edef6bb:web:a30643dc-7034-47ae-b87e-119ef8a2975d" /></ObjectPaths></Request>
```

Fiddler Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 7513
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: 7e19049d-601e-2000-008d-b31e125c7e26
request-id: 7e19049d-601e-2000-008d-b31e125c7e26
X-RequestDigest: 0x1B109C2C5737406AB9E9A2983D743443F86CEF7D92CD6041BB1510FCDD2A4866A55C5BF0D32E4E55C4448C12C9727F191740AAF929E6353320C1CAE0FBBC1D16,07 May 2015 17:27:33 -0000
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4021
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 17:27:40 GMT
Content-Length: 574

[
{
"SchemaVersion":"15.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"16.0.4021.1200","ErrorInfo":{
"ErrorMessage":"Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: 'https:\u002f\u002fslalomdev123.sharepoint.com\u002fsites\u002fPaulDev\u002fcompany\u002fACS\u002fmanuals' OriginalException: The request uses too many resources.","ErrorValue":null,"TraceCorrelationId":"7e19049d-601e-2000-008d-b31e125c7e26","ErrorCode":-2146232832,"ErrorTypeName":"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException"
},"TraceCorrelationId":"7e19049d-601e-2000-008d-b31e125c7e26"
}
]
```

Comment: make sure that the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is activated on the Site collection features firstly., check this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2979882-5b38-4763-b7d5-79feb8dd7098/powershellcsom-cmspublishing0-exception?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: another thought is increase the maxobjectpath to more than 256 then try...http://ojasmaru.blogspot.com/2013/03/error-in-sharepoint-2010-client-object.html

Comment: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is definitely activated.  The site collection was created using the Publishing Portal template.

Answer (score 0):

What's fiddler showing up in the responder||JSON||Tab?

Using PowerShell it is possible to check your web application parameters and tweak them as describes this blog:
[SharePoint Exception: The request uses too many resources](http://mihalech.com/blog/2015/11/sharepoint-exception-the-request-uses-too-many-resources/)

at the same time monitor your server and control that have a enough memory and CPU power to complete the request.